# Is the vacuum energy also a force on moving objects?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, vacuum, casimir-effect

Newton says 'In an inertial reference frame, an object either remains at rest or continues to move at a constant velocity, unless acted upon by a force.'

Now in the casimir effect it seems that plates are pushed together by the virtual particles. But imagine that an object is moving through empty space it is said that it keeps moving according to Newtons'firs law. But the vacuum seems to create a force too, so is it allowed to say that on a moving object in outer space that keeps moving there is no force on it?

Comment: You mix quantum mechanics with Newtonian mechanics?

Answer (score 1):

> But the vacuum seems to create a force too, so is it allowed to say that on a moving object in outer space that keeps moving there is no force on it?

No, not in the sense I think you mean. 
The [Casimir effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect)  has 3 possible mechanisms in it's production, (although this may be a difference of viewpoint, rather than a physical difference, my ignorance regarding field theory is significant) but what I can say is that the effect appears when a restriction is placed on the field's theoretically infinite degrees of freedom by the use of **plates**, not just by a single plate as you mention in your post.

My fairly obvious analogy below is related to your earlier question on this topic, I think I see what you were asking now.

In the Earth's atmosphere, a single plate will feel the same atmospheric force on both sides of it, unless you impart a non trivial velocity to it.
If we have two similiar plates with a vacuum between them, then the atmosphere will push them together, no matter what their velocity is. But it will not affect their velocity as a system, again unless they are travelling at a velocity where air resistance needs to be taken into account.
**But**, you need two plates.

So if you gave a single plate in empty space an arbitrary velocity, the Casimir effect would not have any affect on "pushing" it along, since the vacuum field values on either side of it would be the same.  If you put a double plate separated by a small distance, then the plates may be pushed together by the Casimir force, but then the plates will close up, leaving you with effectively a single  plate, whose velocity is not affected by anything except the initial, "ordinary" force you gave it.

Answer (score 0):

Vacuum only creates a force if there isn't a vacuum on the other side of it as well.

The force is due to a pressure difference, if pressures are the same on both sides (or none) then there is no net force on the plate.  There's the Newtonian side of the answer.